# How can I return a specific node when there are different selection criteria/depths with xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML,

```
<root>
    <property>
        <programs>
            <program>1</program>
            <program>5</program>
        </programs>
        <tool>
        </tool>
    </property>
    <property>
        <tool>
            <programs>
                <program>1</program>
                <program>2</program>
            </programs>
        </tool>
    </property>
</root>
```

how would I write an XPath expression to return a collection containing the "property" nodes when program=1?  I think I want to write something like "give me all the property nodes when self or a descendant contains programs[program=1]", but can't get it to just give me the "property" nodes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
property[.//programs/program=1]
```

Selects the `property` elements that contain descendant `programs` elements that contain a child `program` element who's value is `1`.

Comment: Aha! I knew there had to be a way to do it.  "That was easy!"  Thx

Comment: You mean `property[.//programs/program=1]`. `//` starts at the root, which would lead to *every* property node being returned as long as there is a `program=1` anywhere in the document. `.//` starts at the context node.